# Why am I getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception ?

Tags: java, arrays, break

Why does my code not work? I wanted the following: One enters a number and the program prints out all numbers until the entered number. It is part of a problem of a bigger code of mine. Thats why its important for me to do it with a `while(true)-loop` with a `break` and with an array that would later be printed out.

Letting it run, after entering a number it only says:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>       at yt_brotcr_15ff.yt_brotcr_19_Schmierzettel5.main(yt_brotcr_19_Schmierzettel5.java:14)"

What is the problem?

Here is the code:

```
package yt_brotcr_15ff;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class yt_brotcr_19_Schmierzettel5 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        int hochzähl = 1;
        int eingabeB;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        eingabeB = s.nextInt();
        int[] zahlArray = new int[eingabeB];
        while (true) {
            zahlArray[i] = hochzähl;
            if (i > eingabeB) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
            hochzähl++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j > eingabeB; j++) {
            System.out.println(zahlArray[j]);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: use arraylist instead of array, learn about static and dynamic array intialization,.... **in your last for loop use j<eingableB**

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem....

```
        zahlArray[i] = hochzähl;
```

This line will error if `i` is greater or equal to `eingabeB`.

Your check must happen first:

```
        if (i >= eingabeB) {
            break;
       }
        zahlArray[i] = hochzähl
```

Notice the >= not >

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

is being thrown by this:

```
int[] zahlArray = new int[eingabeB];
    while (true) {
        zahlArray[i] = hochzähl;
        if (i > eingabeB) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
        hochzähl++;
    }
```

The first line creates an array with `eingabeB` entries, starting with 0. Therefore the last entry has index `eingabeB-1`, and not `eingabeB` as your code expects.

There are several ways around this, you could try:

```
if (hochzähl > eingabeB) { // code
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are trying to access array index beyond its size. Please note, array index start from `0` and goes till `length -1`. So, if `zahlArray` size is 4, so maximum array index can be `3`.

Now, imagine `i=3`, which is greater than 4. So, `(i > eingabeB)` would `false`. So, loop continues and increment `i` value to 4. Now, as you know, you can't access index `4` of array size `4`, accessing this index will give you mentioned exception.

```
zahlArray[i] = hochzähl;
if (i > eingabeB) 
{
   break;
}
i++;
hochzähl++;
```

To correct this, you should move `(i > eingabeB)` after incrementing `i` value. It should be like

```
zahlArray[i] = hochzähl;
i++;
if (i > eingabeB) 
{
   break;
}
hochzähl++;
```